# How to fetch the closest image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've used the below code. However, I'm able to take control of the faces in the webcam. However, how to fetch the closest image to the camera.  Can anyone help ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\opencv\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\opencv\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret,img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)
    print len(faces)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
    crop_img = img[y: y + h, x: x + w] #Crop from x, y, w, h->100, 200, 300, 400
        ts = time.time()
        'cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\opencv\\detectedfaces\\"+str(ts)+".jpg", crop_img)'
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+h]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+h]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for(ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
                 cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    time.sleep(5)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')
    if k == 27:
        break;

cap.release()
cv2.destroAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which face is closest to the camera?

Comment: Yes, looking for closest face

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the eye locations, I'd just use IOD (inter-ocular distance). Basically the distance between the center of your two eye ROIs. That metric could be used to infer distance from the camera.

Something like this will do the job:

```
if len(eyes) >= 2:
  IOD = abs((eyes[0][0] + eyes[0][1] / 2.0) - (eyes[1][0] + eyes[1][1] / 2.0))
  cv2.putText(img,'%d'%IOD, (30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 1)
```

It won't be terribly accurate if two people are at roughly the same distance from the camera, but I don't think much will. You could also correlate facial width and IOD to compensate for people with different sized heads.